# TableLayout not being displayed when added dynamically

Tags: android

I'm trying to parse an XML and display its contents in table layout. I'm adding rows and columns dynamically, when execute instead of displaying table, it shows a blank screen.

This is my xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".CaptureActivity" >

<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/ScrollView_maintable"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="400dp" >

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

 </TableLayout>
```

This is my activity class.

```
public class CaptureActivity extends Activity {

private String url = "http://192.168.3.140:8080/EmployeeXmlDemo/EmployeeList.xml";
//private String url = "http://192.168.2.166:8780/capture/clientRequest.do?r=employeeList&cid=0";

FetchEmployeeAsyncTask employeeAsyncTask = new FetchEmployeeAsyncTask(this);

private ArrayList<Employee> employees = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    employeeAsyncTask.execute(new String[] {url});

    System.out.println("Status "+employeeAsyncTask.getStatus());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_capture, menu);
    return true;
}



public void showEmployees(ArrayList<Employee> employees) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("size is "+employees.size());

    TableLayout employeeTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_table);

    TableRow header = new TableRow(this);
    header.setId(100);
    //header.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    TextView empCodeHeader = new TextView(this);
    empCodeHeader.setId(200);
    empCodeHeader.setText("Employee Code");
    empCodeHeader.setTextSize(16);
    empCodeHeader.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
    empCodeHeader.setWidth(200);
    header.addView(empCodeHeader);

    TextView empNameHeader = new TextView(this);
    empNameHeader.setId(201);
    empNameHeader.setText("Employee Name");
    empNameHeader.setTextSize(16);
    empNameHeader.setPadding(2,2,2,2);
    empNameHeader.setWidth(300);
    header.addView(empNameHeader);

    employeeTable.addView(header);//, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));



    for(int i=0; i<employees.size();i++){

        Employee employee = (Employee) employees.get(i);

        int count = 0;

        TableRow empData = new TableRow(this);
        empData.setId(300+count);
        /*empData.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ));*/
        //tr.setClickable(true);

        final TextView empCode = new TextView(this);
        empCode.setId(300+count);
        empCode.setText(employee.getCode());
        empCode.setTextSize(16);
        empCode.setPadding(2,2, 2, 2);
        empData.addView(empCode);

        final TextView empName = new TextView(this);
        empName.setId(300+count);
        empName.setText(employee.getName());
        empName.setTextSize(16);
        empName.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);
        empData.addView(empName);

        employeeTable.addView(empData); /*, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));*/
       count++;

        System.out.println("Name "+employee.getName());
        System.out.println("Designatio "+employee.getDesignation());


    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture);

}



/**
 * @return the employees
 */
public ArrayList<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}

/**
 * @param employees the employees to set
 */
public void setEmployees(ArrayList<Employee> employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
}
```

}

This is my AsyncTask class.

```
public class FetchEmployeeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Employee> >   {

private CaptureActivity activity;

public FetchEmployeeAsyncTask(CaptureActivity nextActivity) {
    this.activity = nextActivity;
}

@Override
protected ArrayList<Employee> doInBackground(String... url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated methoVoidd stub
    ArrayList<Employee> employees = null;
    for(String employeeUrl : url){
        employees = fetch(employeeUrl);
    }
    return employees;
}

private ArrayList<Employee> fetch(String url) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<Employee> employees = null;
    String response = null;
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        employees = EmployeeXMLParser.XMLfromString(response);
        System.out.println("Size in fetch "+employees.size());

        //System.out.println("Employee Name :: " + employees.get(0).getFirstName() + " " + employees.get(0).getLastName());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } /*catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("Error parsing the response :: " + response);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }*/
    return employees;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Employee> employees){
    super.onPostExecute(employees);

    System.out.println("in post execxute "+employees.size());
    activity.showEmployees(employees);
    //activity.setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture);

}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture)
```

remove  that in showEmployee()

Comment: only set it once oncreate(). setting it the second time will reset it to blank.